# Enter value in postgres table using for loop

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to run a query using for loop where i need to enter 50 million record and one column as fixed value and other two as incremented , i have tried using this.

```
FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
INSERT INTO c
SELECT x,98,now()+ i * interval '1 minute'
FROM generate_series(1,50000000) AS x(msisdn);
```

It seems not working
Kindly help

Comment: *"It seems not working"*. Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please explain in detail how exactly what you're trying is "not working". What happens, or does not happen? Are there errors? If so, what's the **exact text** of the error message? Also, what's your PostgreSQL version? What's the schema of `c`? (You should usually have a list of column names, e.g. `c (col1, col2, col3)`). These are questions you will be asked for every post, so please edit your post to include that kind of detail. To learn more, see http://stackoverflow.com/tour and http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a for loop here?

```
INSERT INTO c
SELECT msisdn,98,now()::timestamptz(0) + i * interval '1 minute'
FROM generate_series(1,50000000) AS x(msisdn),
     generate_series(1,10) as i;
```

Make sure it's actually what you want before running it, though, because it's going to take *very* long. For instance, by running:

```
SELECT msisdn,98,now()::timestamptz(0) + i * interval '1 minute'
FROM generate_series(1,5) AS x(msisdn),
     generate_series(1,10) as i;
```

Comment: Yes i want to add these many rows, thanks a lot for this help

Comment: this thing is adding 10 rows for 1..10 i just want a single row for every value..

Comment: Well... so is your original loop, which is why I was prompting you to make sure it's the query you want. :-)

Comment: in a way like 1,98,date then second row is 1,98, date with 1 minute added and like this .. so 50 rows added like this

Comment: I want an output in following way                          1,98,<time>
2,98,<time+any interval )
2,98,<time+interval_

Comment: I think it's what it's doing now, actually. Sort the rows to check: `order by msisdn, i`. (In my case, they're already in the correct order.)

Comment: "so 50 rows added like this" — why your 1..10 loop for i, then? you need to clean up your logic and your requirements somewhat. and I really can't help you much on that.

Comment: was getting confused a bit.. i just want 1,98,time then 2,98,time+interval,3,98,time+interval... how can we do this any idea

Comment: Still unclear, but try `SELECT msisdn,98,now()::timestamptz(0) + msisdn * interval '1 minute' from generate_series(1,5) AS x(msisdn)`